# What is the solution for the path of 'os'

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I am using Windows 10 And I wrote this code

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.dir(BASE_DIR , 'media')
```

then i tried to open the server of django the CMD=terminal said:

```
NameError: name 'os' is not defined)
```

Then I tried to add (import os) but it didn't work also then I added (from settings import PROJECT_ROOT) but it didn't work either so what is the problem?

Comment: What happened when you tried to import os?

Comment: try tagging your question with python to get more people to view your question

Comment: Like Someone_who_likes_SE said: what happened when you tried `import os`? "It didn't work" is not a useful description.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First, did you wrote "import os".

```
# pip3 install os

import os
os.system("echo Hello World")
```

If you can't install os in pip, you pip is broken => try reinstall it!
If so, maybe your python is not on path. Perhabs you added the wrong path. Try to add it to sys-variables. Or the most unlikly case, os is not included, then try "pip3 install os".

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement os (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for os     I tried to install it but he said that

Comment: And I want to ask again where do I write (import os)

Comment: And from where do I import the os?

Comment: pip3 install os

Comment: I improved my question so that you see how it should work.